# MySQL need help.. how can I filter max(date)

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax, max

i have a table assumed like this

[table a]
UID     |    UNAME
------------------
001     |   a
002     |   b
003     |   c

[table b]
UID     |    LOGS
----------------------
001     |  2009/08/01
001     |  2009/08/03
003     |  2009/08/02

and i want to have a query like this
UID     |   LASTLOG
--------------------
001     |  2009/08/03
002     |  NULL
003     |  2009/08/02

that result i have already done it, but i faced a problem while i want to add filter lastlogin, assumed if i entered filter to show all users who has lastlogin before '2009/08/03', i want result like this

UID     |   LASTLOG
--------------------
003     |  2009/08/02

which eliminate UID 001 because 001 has lastlogin at 2009/08/03

i use sql command like this

```
SELECT a.uid, max(logs.date)
FROM user a LEFT JOIN logs ON (a.uid = logs.uid)
where max(logs.date)<'2009/08/03'
group by a.uid
```

how can i add a filter to show only max(logs.date) before 2009/08/03, because line 3 "where max(logs.date)<'2009/08/03' causes an error invalid group by function.
thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.uid, max(logs.date)
FROM user a LEFT JOIN logs ON (a.uid = logs.uid)
group by a.uid
having max(logs.date)<'2009/08/03'
```

Comment: ya that was results no error, but the uid 001 with lastlogin 2009/08/03 still appears.. was having statement dont do filtering?

Comment: Since you're using a string to represent the date, and not MySQL's built-in date type, perhaps there's a space at the end of the '2009/08/03' string?  ('2009/08/03 ' is technically greater than '2009/08/03')

Comment: ohmygosh.. thx, it resolved! i used date type variable but it about a delimiters. mysql dont use '/' but '-' lol.. tq all guys=)

Answer (score 3):

Any condition that uses a grouping function needs to go in the `HAVING` clause like so:

```
SELECT a.uid, max(logs.date)
FROM user a LEFT JOIN logs ON (a.uid = logs.uid)
GROUP BY a.uid
HAVING MAX(logs.date)<'2009/08/03'
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the SQL ["having"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) clause:

```
SELECT a.uid, max(logs.date)
FROM user a LEFT JOIN logs ON (a.uid = logs.uid)
group by a.uid
having max(logs.date) < '2009/08/03'
```

You need to use "having" instead of "where" to test the value of aggregate functions.

Comment: ya it eliminates the error, but why UID 001 with 2009/08/03 still appears? is that any exceptions for date type?